# PHP Soap (Server)

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a webservice using the PHP Soap extension and I am having problems with the .wsdl. Is there an easy way to generate 2.0 wsdl's? Where is a good site (or book) that I can look to in order to determine how to build the WSDL? I have no problem getting my soap client to retrieve soap messages from other web services so I know soap is installed and working. I have found a few links out there that generate WSDL's for you, but most of the sites are down. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not have a built-in WSDL generation utility.  I would recommend using [`Zend_Soap_Server`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html#zend.soap.server) which supports WSDL generation via its [Autodiscover](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html) feature.

Comment: I used Zend's Autodiscover and it worked like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.